# How to write a 'get/set method' for an array of type class?

Tags: java, class, methods, get, set

I'm having trouble in the implementation of a get/set method for an array autores[] of type Autor which is another class from the same package. It doesn't work in the same way as the other variables of the class :(

```
class Autor
{
private String nombre;
private String adscripcion;

Autor(String nombre,String adscripcion)
{
    this.nombre=nombre;
    this.adscripcion=adscripcion;
}
Autor(){}

String getNombre()
{
    return nombre;
}
String getAdscripcion()
{
    return adscripcion;
}

void setNombre(String nombre)
{
    this.nombre=nombre;
}

void setAdscripcion(String adscripcion)
{
    this.adscripcion=adscripcion;
}
```

}
    public class Articulo {

```
private String nombreArt;
private Autor autores[]=new Autor[2];
private String fechaPublicacion;

Articulo(String nombreArt,String fechaPublicacion, String nombre,String adscripcion)
{
    this.nombreArt=nombreArt;
    this.fechaPublicacion=fechaPublicacion;
    autores[0]=new Autor(nombre,adscripcion);
    autores[1]=new Autor(nombre,adscripcion);

}


String getnombreArt()
{
    return nombreArt;
}
String getfechaPublicacion()
{
    return fechaPublicacion;
}
Autor getautores()
{
    return autores[];//this part of the code it's not correct.
}


}
```

Comment: Please share error details and brief what is your required?

Comment: it says  it cannot find symbol

Comment: I just want to return the array autores[] of type Autor, in a similar way as I did it for the String nombreArt.

Comment: Have you tried @Elliott Frisch answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getter should look like

```
public Autor[] getAutores()
{
    return autores;
}
```

and the setter is like

```
public void setAutores(Autor[] autores) {
    this.autores = autores;
}
```

If you use an IDE like Eclipse, then are menu options to generate setter/getter and heaps of other things

Comment: How can I call the method setAutores in the main class? I'd like to put the name of an autor as parameter of setAutores method, but it turns out autores is a String, what can I do?

Comment: First you need to construct a `Autor` from your `String`s and then create a Autor array, then you can pass it to your setter

Comment: this is the Autor array `Autor z[];` but I don't understand how to construct a `Autor` from the `String`?

Comment: :D.. I can't post it in comments, do I edit my question to post the whole code?

Comment: yes, edit your question and add (not the whole code) the constrcutor

Comment: I added the class Autor

Comment: So you can see the the `Autor` has this constructor `Autor(String nombre,String adscripcion)` which takes two Strings

Answer (score 1):

First, `autores` can be declared with your current syntax - but it's a hold-over to make Java more familiar to C and C++ developers. I personally find it easier to read with the type fully on the left of the variable name. Like,

```
private Autor[] autores = new Autor[2];
```

For getters and setters of array types, the `[]` must be written as part of the type. Like,

```
public Autor[] getAutores() {
    return autores;
}

public void setAutores(Autor[] autores) {
    this.autores = autores;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This part doesn't make any sense;

```
return autores[];
```

`autores` is a variable name and it's an array of `Autor` objects. So your getter should be something like that,

```
public Autor[] getAutores() {
    return autores;
}
```

In here, `Autor[]` is return type and it will return value of `autores` variable.

Comment: I think OP is confused because Java allows the declaration `Autor autores[]`.

Comment: Exactly!. Its better when declaring arrays use, `Autor[] autores`